# Obtaining the file name component of a path

Tags: python, path

Trying to convert this Perl code into Python:

```
$path = shift;
$path =~ /.*\/(.*)/;
$filename = $1;
if (0 == length($filename)) {
    $filename = $path;  }
```

The code produces the file name component of a path. For example, It gives `$filename = "bar.txt";` for `$path = foo/bar.txt`. The path in question is the first argument passed to the script.

I know nothing about Perl and just learned Python last week, hence my problem. My attempt is:

```
path = os.path.basename(sys.path.pop(0))
fil = sys.argv.pop()
if (0 == len(fil)):
    fil = path
```

Comment: you should try to code it and post the code if it doesn't work

Comment: What part of the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is not clear? Where did you get stuck with using the module? Did you notice that capturing groups are exposed through the returned match object?

Comment: @daouzli i added my attempt, this is just returning the name of my script, not the file its working on.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @daouzli i edited in my task

Comment: I think the perl script take the first command line argument that should be an absolute folder and keep the basename and filename seems to take the second argument if any else path.

Comment: (Note that you should have used File::Basename's `basename` in Perl. Kudos for going that route in Python.)

Answer (score 1):

You're right to use `os.path.basename`. The only issue is that the command line args come from `sys.argv`.

```
import sys, os
path = sys.argv[1]
fn = os.path.basename(path)
print(fn)
```

Comment: i get this error .. File ".git_filters/rcs-keywords.smudge", line 81, in <module>
    path = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It's hard to find the file name of a path you didn't provide

Comment: Im trying to get the file name of the git file which is being smudged.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: @gung, I though saying `os.path.basename` finds the `basename` was sufficiently implied, but I can add it.

Comment: It does seem implied, @ikegami. I was just noting that the post was being automatically flagged as low quality.

Comment: @gung, Honestly, this is my second time writing any Python, so I kept it simple to avoid saying something incorrect.